# Batch code that boots up minecraft servers

Tags: batch

I have some code that boots up a minecraft server, more complicated then most. I'm looking for some positive criticism on how to improve my code (and coding practice!).

**File:**

````
::Copyright notice
::RandomWords.py
::By Dylan Prins
::
::This work is licensed under CC BY 4.0.
::To view a copy of this license, visit
::https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0

::bootstrap
:bootstrap
@echo off
title %sver% %sname%
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist "runfig.conf" set "fig=True"
if NOT exist "runfig.conf" set "fig=False"
echo MConsole Beta
echo.
echo Config loaded?
if %fig% == True goto confLoad
echo %fig%
ping 0 >nul
goto question

::Load the stuffs
:confLoad
echo %fig%
< runfig.conf (
  set /p fname=
  set /p name=
  set /p mem=
  set /p sname=
  set /p sver=
)
echo.
echo %fname%
echo %name%
echo %mem%
echo %sname%
echo %sver%
echo.
title %sver% %sname%
ping 0 >nul

::main menu
:question
cls
echo %sver% %sname% Main Menu
echo Type 'help' for help and type 'settings' for the settings menu
echo.
set /p "option=>"
if %option% == boot goto boot
if %option% == bootnorm goto quesbootnorm
if %option% == help set "menu=main" && goto help
if %option% == settings goto settings
if %option% == vars goto vars
if %option% == refresh cls && goto bootstrap
if %option% == exit exit
goto question

::boot modded
:boot
cls
echo.
echo Booting...
echo.
java -Xmx%mem%G -Xms%mem%G -jar %fname%.jar nogui
ping 0 >nul
pause
goto question

::Ask if booting the vanilla server is what they want
:quesbootnorm
cls
echo.
echo WARNING: Booting a modded server in vanilla mode can corrupt the world!
echo.
set /p "option=Continue? (y/n)"
if %option% == y goto bootnorm
if %option% == Y goto bootnorm
if %option% == N goto question
if %option% == n goto question
echo.
echo Invalid choice (y/n)
echo.
pause
goto quesbootnorm

:: Boot vanilla server
:bootnorm
cls
echo.
echo You have been warned!
echo Booting...
echo.
java -Xmx%mem%G -Xms500M -jar %name%.jar nogui
ping 0 >nul
pause
goto question

::set the name of the forge file
:fnameset
cls
echo What do you want to set the name of the forge file to (without the .jar)
echo It is currently "%fname%"
echo.
set /p "fname=>"
echo.
echo Name set to "%fname%"
echo Don't forget to run saveconf if you wish to save these changes!
echo.
pause
goto settings

::set the name of the vanilla boot file
:nameset
cls
echo What do you want to set the name of the regular file to (without the .jar)
echo It is currently "%name%"
echo.
set /p "name=>"
echo.
echo Name set to "%name%"
echo Don't forget to run saveconf if you wish to save these changes!
echo.
pause
goto settings

::save current name(s) to file
:saveconf
cls
echo Do you wish to save these files into config file for later?
echo.
echo (Forge server name) - %fname%
echo (Vanilla server name) - %name%
echo (Memory) - %mem%GB
echo (Server name) - %sname%
echo (Server version) - %sver%
echo.
set /p "option=Continue? (y/n)"
if %option% == y goto dosaveconf
if %option% == Y goto dosaveconf
if %option% == N goto settings
if %option% == n goto settings
echo.
echo Invalid choice (y/n)
echo.
pause
goto saveconf

::actually save the config
:dosaveconf
echo.
echo %fname%>runfig.conf && echo Saving "%fname%" to file...
echo %name%>>runfig.conf && echo Saving "%name%" to file...
echo %mem%>>runfig.conf && echo Saving "%mem%" to file...
echo %sname%>>runfig.conf && echo Saving "%sname%" to file...
echo %sver%>>runfig.conf && echo Saving "%sver%" to file...
echo.
echo Save complete!
pause
goto settings

::set the memory cap
:memory
cls
echo The current memory cap is "%mem%GB"
echo What would you like to change it to? (without the 'GB' just the number)
set /p "mem=>"
echo.
echo Memory cap changed to "%mem%GB"
echo Don't forget to run saveconf if you wish to save these changes!
echo.
pause
goto settings

::Variables list
:vars
echo.
echo %mem%GB
echo %fname%.jar
echo %name%.jar
echo %sname%
echo %sver%
echo.
pause
goto question

::self explanitory
:help
cls
echo.
echo Help menu
echo.
echo Main
echo.
echo boot - Reboot modded server
echo bootnorm - Reboot normal server
echo help - Show this list
echo exit - Exit
echo.
echo Settings
echo.
echo memory - Set the max memory cap
echo setforgename - Set the name of the forge server file
echo setname - Set the name of the normal server file
echo saveconf - Save the current name(s) to a conf file
echo sname - Set the server name
echo sver - Set the server version
echo.
echo Debug (main)
echo.
echo vars - List all current loaded variables
echo refresh - Start the console again from bootstrap
echo.
pause
if %menu% == main goto question
if %menu% == set goto settings
echo.
echo Error code 1; value "menu" is "%menu%"
echo.
pause
goto question

::Set server name
:sname
cls 
echo The current server name is "%sname%"
echo What would you like to change it to?
set /p "sname=>"
echo.
echo Server name changed to "%sname%"
echo Don't forget to run saveconf if you wish to save these changes!
echo.
pause
goto settings

::Set server version
:sver
cls 
echo The current server version is "%sver%"
echo What would you like to change it to?
set /p "sver=>"
echo.
echo Server version changed to "%sver%"
echo Don't forget to run saveconf if you wish to save these changes!
echo.
pause
goto settings

:settings
cls
echo %sver% %sname% Settings Menu
echo Type 'help' for help
echo.
set /p "option=>"
if %option% == setforgename goto fnameset
if %option% == setname goto nameset
if %option% == saveconf goto saveconf
if %option% == memory goto memory
if %option% == help set goto help
if %option% == sname goto sname
if %option% == sver goto sver
if %option% == help set "menu=set" && goto help
if %option% == exit goto question
goto settings
```
````

Comment: i am working on the script, can you make a flowchart (just a simple one)? `GOTO` is a mess...

Comment: Alright, working on a flowchart now

Comment: in my answer i'm currently working on, i mostly use `CALL`, but sometimes `GOTO` is necessary.

Comment: Hey, while scrolling through my code i just released in the :settings menu 'help' is listed twice. That's a mistake, and you can probably delete the one that's listed which does not change the 'menu' variable.

Comment: https://app.lucidchart.com/invitations/accept/f065b40b-5cae-4e59-8a18-5269f2f0f55a
This looks like it covers everything, PNG link: https://i.imgur.com/a/akZOhpD.png incase you dont want to make a lucidchart account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely omitted the `:HELP` section by adding description to labels

```
:label - Description here
```

and [`FINDSTR`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to search the script for descriptions.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions


REM Define variables
=:: User-defined
set "conf=runfig.conf"
set "#MAIN=boot bootnorm settings" MAIN section
set "#SETTINGS=memory setforgename setname saveconf sname sver" SETTINGS section
set "#DEBUG=vars refresh help exit" DEBUG section
=:: Initalized
(set LF=^
%=-----DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE. Expands to nothing.-----=%
)
set ^"NL=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^" Escaped LF gets ignored, next LF always escaped


====:BOOTSTRAP
cls
title %sver% %sname%

if EXIST "%conf%" (set "fig=True") ELSE set "fig=false"
echo MConsole Beta
echo Config loaded? %fig%

if "%fig%" == "True" goto :confLoad
>nul ping 127.1
goto :MENU


====:CONFLOAD - Load the stuffs
echo %fig%
<"%conf%" (FOR %%V in (fname name mem sname sver) do (
    set/p"%%V="
    echo(!%%V!
))
title %sver% %sname%
>nul ping 127.1


====:MENU - main menu
cls
echo %sver% %sname% Main Menu
echo Type 'help' for help and type 'settings' for the settings menu

set "option="
set/p"option=>"

cls
=:: EXIT, a special case all by itself
if "!option!" == "exit" exit /b
FOR %%O in (%#MAIN% %#DEBUG%) do if "!option!" == "%%O" call :%%O

goto :MENU


:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::MAIN
:boot - boot modded
echo Booting...

java -Xmx%mem%G -Xms%mem%G -jar %fname%.jar nogui
>nul ping 127.1

pause >nul&exit /b


:bootnorm - Boot vanilla server
echo WARNING: Booting a modded server in vanilla mode can corrupt the world!

CHOICE /C yn /M "Continue?"
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto :MENU

echo You have been warned!
echo Booting...

java -Xmx%mem%G -Xms500M -jar %name%.jar nogui
>nul ping 127.1

pause >nul&exit /b


:settings
cls
echo %sver% %sname% Settings Menu
echo Type 'help' for help

set "option="
set/p"option=>"

cls
if "!option!" == "exit" goto :MENU
FOR %%O in (%#SETTINGS% %#DEBUG%) do if "!option!" == "%%O" call :%%O

goto :settings


:
::::SETTINGS
:memory - set the memory cap
echo The current memory cap is "%mem%GB"
echo What would you like to change it to? (without the 'GB' just the number)
set/p"mem=>"
echo Memory cap changed to "%mem%GB"
echo Don't forget to run saveconf if you wish to save these changes!
pause >nul
goto :settings


:setforgename - set the name of the forge file
echo What do you want to set the name of the forge file to (without the .jar)
echo It is currently "%fname%"

set/p"fname=>"
echo Name set to "%fname%"
echo Don't forget to run saveconf if you wish to save these changes!

pause >nul&exit /b


:setname - set the name of the vanilla boot file
echo What do you want to set the name of the regular file to (without the .jar)
echo It is currently "%name%"

set/p"name=>"
echo Name set to "%name%"
echo Don't forget to run saveconf if you wish to save these changes!

pause >nul&exit /b


:saveconf - save current name(s) to file
=:: Prompt for user
echo Do you wish to save these files into config file for later?%NL%

(Forge server name) - %fname%%NL%
(Vanilla server name) - %name%%NL%
(Memory) - %mem%GB%NL%
(Server name) - %sname%%NL%
(Server version) - %sver%

CHOICE /C yn /M "Continue?"
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 goto :settings

=:: Really save the config
>"%conf%" (FOR %%V in (fname name mem sname sver) do (
echo(!%%V!
>&3 echo Saving "%fname%" to file...
))
echo Save complete!

pause >nul&exit /b


:sname - Set server name
:sver - Set server version
set "var=%0"
set "var=!var:~1!"

echo The current server name is "!%var%!"
echo What would you like to change it to?
set/p"%var%=>"
echo Server name changed to "!%var%!"
echo Don't forget to run saveconf if you wish to save these changes!

pause >nul&exit /b



:
::::DEBUG
:vars - Variables list
echo %mem%GB%NL%
  %fname%.jar%NL%
  %name%.jar%NL%
  %sname%%NL%
  %sver%

pause >nul&exit /b


:refresh - Start the console again from bootstrap
goto :BOOTSTRAP


:help - Show this list
echo Help menu
findstr /R "^:" "%~f0"

pause >nul&cls&exit /b


:exit - Exit
exit /b
```

---

Rules:

## 1. **[NEVER](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWJTsKaJT_g) trust user input.** Use `!DELAYED EXPANSION!`

2. Use `CALL` instead of `GOTO`
3. Use `FOR` loops to shorten repetitive commands
4. Use `CHOICE` instead of `SET /P`
5. When you want to `ECHO` a multi-line string, the *"normal"* way to do it is:

   ```
   echo foo
   echo bar
   echo foobar
   ```

   but it can be very slow, depending on how many `ECHO`s there are.
   A faster and more readable way is to create a [line continuation character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455750/12861751) yourself (`\n` + `^`):

   ```
   (set LF=^
   %=-----DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE. Expands to nothing.-----=%
   )
   set ^"NL=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"
   echo foo%NL%
   bar%NL%
   foobar
   ```
6. **Always** use full paths (use [variables](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6137) like `%__CD__%`/`%__APPDIR__%`), *not* relative paths for external commands, but i didn't do it here

Comment: I don't really know the proper etiquette on what to do once you've gotten a code review, but tysm!